# VariesAcrossGroups lost when ReInsert_ing doc.ParameterBindings?

Tags: revit-api

Our plugin maintains some instance parameter values across many elements, including those in groups.
Occasionally the end users will introduce data that activates an unused Category,
so we have to update the document parameter bindings, to include those categories. However, when we call

```
doc.ParameterBindings.ReInsert()
```

our existing parameter values inside groups are lost, because our VariesAcrossGroups flag is toggled back to false?

How did Revit intend this to work - are we supposed to use this in a different way, to not trigger this problem?

ReInsert() expects a base Definition argument, and would usualy get an ExternalDefinition supplied.

To learn, I instead tried to scan through the definition-keys of existing bindings and match those.
This way, I got the document's InternalDefinition, and tried calling Reinsert with that instead
(my hope was, that since its existing InternalDefinition DID include VariesAcrossGroups=true, this would help). Alas, Reinsert  doesn't seem to care.

The problem, as you might guess, is that after VariesAcrossGroups=False, a lot of my instance parameters have collapsed into each other, so they all hold identical values. Given that they are IDs, this is less than ideal.

My current (intended) solution is to instead grab a backup of all existing parameter values BEFORE I update the bindings, then after the binding-update and variesAcrossGroups back to true, then inspect all values and re-assign all parameter-values that have been broken. But as you may surmise, this is less than ideal - it will be horribly slow for the users to use our plugin, and frankly it seems like something the revitAPI should take care of, not the plugin developer.

Are we using this the wrong way?

One approach I have considered, is to bind every possibly category I can think of, up front and once only. But I'm not sure that is possible. Categories in themselves are also difficult to work with, as you can only create them indirectly, by using your Project-Document as a factory (i.e. you cannot create a category yourself, you can only indirectly ask the Document to - maybe! - create a category for you, that you request). Because of this, I don't think you can bind for all categories up front - some categories only become available  in the document, AFTER you have included a given family/type in your project.

To sum it up: First, I

```
doc.ParameterBindings.ReInsert()
```

my binding, with the updated categories. Then, I call

```
InternalDefinition.SetAllowVaryBetweenGroups()
```

(after having determined IDEF.VariesAcrossGroups has reverted back to false.)
I am interested to hear the best way to do this, without destroying the client's existing data.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: By the way, in the debugger I tried holding on to the existing InternalDefinition, which had VariesAcrossGroups = true.
  As soon as ParameterBindings.ReInsert() returns, its VariesAcrossGroups flag has flipped to false.
So it's not even a case of the old one being destroyed and a new one being created. The existing one  is simply reset to false. At least, that's how the revit api exposes it.

Comment: a further 'tip', for anyone running into this same, unsolved problem:
   I have 'solved' it so far, simply by scanning through THE ENTIRE REVIT DB, and picking up a copy of my parameter values (indexed by element id), before I update the document bindings. 
    Immediately after, I reactivate the lost 'allowVaryBetweenGroups'.
   Then, afterwards, I iterate through my collected element parameters, and check which of them have lost their value, and if so, reset them back to their intended value.

Comment: A trick which speeds this up a bit, is that I only collect for elements, which have Element.GroupId <> -1 (that is, form part of a group.)
  This works, because it is specifically group members that are damaged.
Another tip is, that you both have to watch out for LOST values, but also for WRONGLY set values. That is, you must also remember to reset back to 'unset',
if this revit bug has accidentally set a parameter that shouldn't really be set.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not sure I will accept my own answer).
My answer is just, that you can survive-circumvent this problem,
by scanning the entire revit database for your existing parmater values, before you update the document bindings.
Afterwards, you reset VariesAcrossGroups back to its lost value.
Then, you iterate through your collected parameters, and verify which ones have lost their original value, and reset them back to their intended value.

One trick that speeds this up a bit, is that you can check Element.GroupId <> -1. That is, those elements that are group members.
You only need to track elements which are group members, as it's precisely those that are affected by this Revit bug.
A further tip is, that you should not only watch out for parameter-values that have lost their original value. You must also watch out for parameter-values that have accidentally GOTTEN a value, but which should be left un-set.

I just use FilteredElementCollector with WhereElementIsNotElementType().
Performance-wise, it is of course horrible to do all this,
but given how Revit behaves, I see no other solution if you have to ship to your clients.